# How to show rows from mySQL from a particular date using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

In mySQL I have a timestamp column named **when**

```
2015-01-07 16:43:21
```

My question is how using PHP/mySQL

For now I can show the results based on month number like

```
... where month(`when`) = '1' ...
```

but what if I want to show the rows of a particular date for example 2015-01-05 ?

I will pass the preferable date through a variable into the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the `date()` function around your date string which is already in the YYYY-MM-DD format, and also around your timestamp field in the where clause:

```
select * from table where date(`when`) = date('2015-01-05');
```

From the documentation for [date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to convert the date via MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`when`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS my_date
FROM
  my_table
WHERE 
  MONTH(`when`) = 1;
```

Take a look at the MySQL documentation here for other formats: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format